# single file Json Parsing to multiple java objects

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a Json file which i want to parse and store it to different objects based on a particular value in the json using java?
I have a file of this type :

```
{
    "TEST_ID": "INV_CRE_184",
    "TEST_DESCRIPTION": "This validate Invoice Creation by mocking dependency",
    "TEST_PLAN": "LINK",
    "TEST_VARIABLE": [{
        "retailcountryCode": "DE"
    }],
    "TEST_CASE": [{
        "OUTPUT_PLACEHOLDER": "V1",
        "ACTION": "Generate",
        "PARAMETERS": [
            "GenerateVendor",
            "VENDOR",
            "${retailcountryCode}"
        ]
    }, {
        "OUTPUT_PLACEHOLDER": "P1",
        "ACTION": "Generate",
        "PARAMETERS": [
            "GeneratePayee",
            "${V1}",
            "${ofaOrg}"
        ]
    },
```

I have two objects V1 and P1 and according to the placeholder values they must be parsed respectively

Comment: Use JSON parser like Gson from google or Jackson

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please show your efforts.

Comment: it is possible using Java.

Comment: I would recommend using [simplejson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/), works great for reading JSON-files.